# iOS 4 and 5 compatibility : Prompt users to update iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, compatibility

The skinny: my app works excellently in iOS 5.x. However, certain features do not work so well in 4.x. All is resolved with an update to 5.x.

Option 1 - Good programmer: find out what was done in my app with these particular features and why they don't work in 4.x.

Option 2 - Lazy programmer: detect the version of iOS the user is running (I'm already aware that this is not advised) and suggest they upgrade if it's older. Even further, lead them to Settings/Software Update through the use of iPhone URL (eg: iossettings://).

Your advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Settings/software update won't work since that was only added in 5.9

Comment: @FrederickCheung you mean 5.0.

Comment: Is is the *bad* form of lazy; not the kind that drives a programmer to automate boring, manual tasks, but the kind that gives the programmer an excuse not to fix a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question may not suit StackOverflow very well, but I'll provide my thoughts. Support the platform or don't support the platform. If you don't support iOS 4, then don't support it and compile the app to require iOS5. If you do support it, then fix the bugs. Don't support it but nag the user. That's just lazy as you say.

Many apps have already moved to iOS5-only. Unless your market is unusual and is particularly likely to have iOS4, then I would drop iOS4 support and move on. The time you waste supporting it won't translate into enough sales to cover it for most apps IMO. And the bad reviews you get on iOS4 will outweigh the few extra sales you might get there. Pick an audience and delight them.

Comment: If you just remove support for iOS4 it won't let anyone download it that can't run it... exactly as Rob said if I downloaded an app that said it was going to work only get to a message saying it doesn't i would be pissed and leave as many 1 star reviews on separate accounts as I could until Apple banned me.

Comment: Good advice. We're only shooting to support iOS 4.x because of a figure I came across (linked below) showing ipad/iphone 4.x usage at around 15%. I agree, dropping iOS is ideal considering the majority of devices (correct me if i'm wrong, 3gs and up) are capable of upgrading to 5 and time is better spent on other problems. Thank you. 

http://david-smith.org/blog/2012/03/10/ios-5-dot-1-upgrade-stats/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Most people are running iOS 4 because their devices don't support iOS 5. Option 1 makes a lot more sense. Or just don't support iOS 4 at all.